# math.floor(N) vs N // 1

Tags: python, math, floor

I am wondering if anyone can give me any insight into how the following may be the same / different in **Python3**:

```
N // 1
```

and

```
from math import floor
floor(N)
```

I tried the following, which seems to indicate that they are equivalent:

```
import math
import random

for _ in range(0, 99999):
    f = random.random()
    n = random.randint(-9999, 9999)
    N = f * n
    n_div = N // 1; n_mth = math.floor(N)
    if n_div != n_mth:
        print("N // 1: {} | math.floor(N): {}".format(n_div, n_mth))
else: # yes, I realize this will always run
    print("Seem the same to me")
```

Thanks for comments below. Updated test to the following, which clearly shows `float // N` returns a `float`, while `math.floor(N)` returns an `int` **in python3**. As I understand it, this behavior is different in **python2**, where `math.ceil` and `math.floor` return `float`s.

Also note how unusual/silly it would be to use `math.ceil` or `math.floor` on an `int` instead of a `float`: either function operating on an `int` simply returns that `int`.

```
import math
import random

for _ in range(0, 99):
    N = random.uniform(-9999, 9999)
    n_div = N // 1; n_mth = math.floor(N)
    if n_div != n_mth:
        print("N: {} ... N // 1: {} | math.floor(N): {}".format(N, n_div, n_mth))
    elif type(n_div) != type(n_mth):
        print("N: {} ... N // 1: {} ({}) | math.floor(N): {} ({})".format(N, n_div, type(n_div), n_mth, type(n_mth)))
else:
    print("Seem the same to me")
```

Comment: It's all the same.

Comment: `//` returns a `float` and `floor` returns an `int`?

Comment: @tobias_k in Python 3, `math.float()` and `math.ceil()` return `ints`

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner Yes, that's exactly what I said.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will spot a difference when using floats:

```
>>> 1000.5//1
1000.0
>>> floor(1000.5)
1000
```

`floor` returns an integer. For most cases `1000` and `1000.0` are equivalent, but not always.

Answer (score 6):

1. `math.floor(N)` returns an int, and `N // 1` returns a float.

   ```
   >>> type(math.floor(-4.4))
   <class 'int'>
   >>> type((-4.4) // 1)
   <class 'float'>
   ```
2. Because of this `floor(nan)` will raise ValueError while `nan // 1` returns NaN (similar for ±inf.)

   ```
   >>> math.floor(math.nan)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
   >>> math.nan // 1
   nan
   ```

I don't think there are other differences when N is a float, since `x//y` is defined as ⌊x/y⌋.

Comment: I think this answer is practically correct, because you can expect to use a these functions only on floats.

Answer (score 6):

`math.floor` first tries to use the `__floor__` magic method, if it does not exist it instead uses `__float__` and then floors that, so it will work when the object supports `__floor__` or can be cast to a `float`.

`x//1` uses the `__floordiv__` magic method and if that is not defined or returns `NotImelemeted` it  then tries `__rfloordiv__` on the integer `1` which will almost certainly be `NotImplemented`, so this would require `__floordiv__` to be implemented on the object in question.

```
from math import floor

class MyInt(int):
    def __floor__(self):
        print("using __floor__")
        return int.__floor__(self)
    def __floordiv__(self,other):
        print("using __floordiv__")
        return int.__floordiv__(self,other)

>>> x = MyInt(5)
>>> floor(x)
using __floor__
5
>>> x//1
using __floordiv__
5
```

Normally the two values will always be **equal** but may implement the two differently, usually the only noticable difference is the **type** of the return value although there can be more substantial changes depending on what kind of object you are using:

```
>>> x = numpy.array([1.5, 2.3, 5])
>>> x//1
array([ 1.,  2.,  5.])
>>> floor(x)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    floor(x)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```